# Why do I get a CORS error with React, axios and Flask?

Tags: reactjs, flask, redux, axios, cors

I know that this has been asked so many times, but none of the answers I've found seems to work. My app is React frontend and Flask backend via an api. I have just switched to axios from the usual await fetch and it keeps throwing CORS errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5050/api/user/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My code is thus:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json" ,
    },
}

const customFetch = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5050',
});

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/registerUser',
    async (user, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const resp=await customFetch.post('/api/user/register', user, config);
            return resp.data ;
        }catch (error) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data.msg);
            
        }
    }
);
```

My server has

```
CORS(app)
```

now also added:

```
@app.after_request
def add_security_headers(resp):
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']='*'
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods']='GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
    resp.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]="Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    return resp
```

and in any case it works ok for a standard:

```
  await fetch(`${api_host}/api/user/register`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data here ...
        }),
      });
```

its driving me mad, any clues? Thanks

UPDATE

Just in case there isn't enough info here are the request and response headers:

**General**

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:5050/api/user/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Request**

```
POST /api/user/register HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 110
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5050
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27
sec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="105", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Connection: close
Server: Werkzeug/2.0.0 Python/3.8.10
Date: Fri, 09 Sep 2022 17:52:09 GMT
```

Once again, any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: CORS on the server side is not working, as you can see in the serialized response there is no "Access-Control-..." header. Also some internal error. I'd try to debug the flask app. Btw you don't need to set this header on the client side. It's only relevant when a client like a browser (where security is in place) sends requests to external domains.

Comment: thanks @timotgl. I've removed the client side header (doh!). It seems as if the extra headers I added server side worked.

Answer (score -1):

I added the following headers server-side, and it seems to have solved it.
I dont know why it stopped working when I switched axios. With standard asyc call it was fine.

```
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']='*'
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods']='GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
resp.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]="Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Comment: Glad it worked, but there must be an easier way in flask than setting these headers manually, maybe check the doc of the CORS middleware/plugin.

Comment: Yes maybe, and I suspect that it is not the most secure way of doing it either!